# Can't install Win7 on Intel SSD X25-M - no driver found in installer ISO

Tags: windows-7, drivers, ssd, sata

Exact SSD model: Intel SSDSA2M080G2GC 2.5"
Laptop I'm trying to install Windows 7 Pro x64 on is a **Dell Latitude E5430**
With this being an older laptop I thought the small SSD (it's 80 GB capacity) would work, but apparently the drivers for it are not in any Win7 ISO I can find. [I did find the Intel page for the SSD](https://ark.intel.com/products/56601/Intel-SSD-X25-M-Series-80GB-2_5in-SATA-3Gbs-34nm-MLC), but all it lists for "Drivers" available is the "SetupRST.exe" which I don't think can be loaded as a disk driver during Win7 install...?

I got the Win7 ISO installer directly from support.Dell.com via the service tag, so I know it's a driver issue with the SSD, but I can't seem to find it. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to extract the exe. Try running it, it may extract to a temp folder or use 7-zip to try and extract.

Comment: You won’t be able to find an ISO that contains the driver you need which means you have to make your own.

Comment: Are you sure the SSD is even working? Is it detected in BIOS/UEFI? BTW, the "setupRST.exe" file isn't drivers and has nothing to do with the SSD (SATA drives do NOT require drivers) but with "Intel Rapid Storage Technology", i.e., software for a motherboard's controller, something Dell Latitude E5430 doesn't have, otherwise it would have been included in the OEM image. In almost all certainty you're dealing with a dead drive, not at all surprising for a SSD from 2009!

Comment: Thanks, all. The SSD is seen by Windows during the install, but I just get  "Windows cannot be installed to the Disk 0 Partition. Error: 0x803000001"

Comment: I extracted the "SetupRST.exe" via 7-zip, burned it to a CD but none of the drivers are listed as "compatible."

Comment: You don’t need a driver, if WinPE can detect the drive, it means a driver exists.  Your drive is dead.  **You failed to me to that error.**

Comment: @KidACrimson Intel RST drivers won’t solve your current problem.

Comment: @Ramhound, ok thanks. I found it in storage, so I guess it is indeed just defective since it's so old.

Comment: You also failed to me mention that, although, nobody buys a new 9 year old product :-$

Comment: Usually drives get marked as "bad" then DBAN'd and securely destroyed, so I just assumed this was one was good, but it must have just been missed.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm the following things:

1. You have your secure boot and UEFI settings disabled in your BIOS. You should have “legacy” boot options enabled.
2. You have set your SATA controllers to AHCI mode in the BIOS.
3. You have removed all partitions and configured your SSD for an MBR partition scheme. You can get to a command prompt in Windows setup by pressing Shift-F10. The perform the procedure outlined here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc725797(v=ws.11) using the command line options.

Reboot and restart Windows setup after this. When asked where to install Windows, choose the empty drive and click ‘Next.’